# Python 3.6 no module named ... On windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-server-2008-r2

I've written a small python script to perform basic tasks. On my local machine everything work fine. But when i go live on **Windows Server 2008 R2** i get this error by executig the **entry point run.py**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in 
     import Worker
Python 3.6 no module named workers
I don't really see what i'm doing wrong, everything seems normal.

This is my folder structure

```
db_utils
entity
files_utils
workers
  __pycache__
  __init__.py
  Worker.py
run.py
```

The code for run.py is

```
from workers.Worker import Worker
import time
import os

    while(True):
        try:
            print("Beginning")
            worker = Worker()
            worker.sendEmails()
            print("Execution successfull")
        except Exception as e:
            if hasattr(e, 'message'):
                print(e.message)
            else:
                print("Execution error")        
        finally:
            time.sleep(10)
```

And the code for Worker.py is

```
from db_utils.DBManager import SessionFactory
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from entity.Email import Email
from pushs.Emailer import Emailer


class Worker():

    _DATE_FORMAT = '%%Y-%%m-%%d'

    _SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

    def getUnsentEmail(self):
        """ Cette fonction retourne la liste des emails qui n'ont pas encore été envoyés"""

        sessionFactory = SessionFactory()
        session = sessionFactory.Session()

        emails = []

        connection = sessionFactory.getConnection()
        query = "select *  from post_email where statut = 'PENDING' "

        result = connection.execute(query)
        for row in result:            
            tmpElt = Email(row)
            emails.append(tmpElt)

        #à ce niveau on a tous les mails qui n'ont pas encore étés envoyés    
        #
        session.close()

        return emails


    def sendEmails(self):

        emails = self.getUnsentEmail()

        sessionFactory = SessionFactory()
        session = sessionFactory.Session()                           
        connection = sessionFactory.getConnection()



        for email in emails:
            emailer = Emailer()
            result = emailer.sendEmail(email)

            #si le résultat est False le mail n'a pas été envoyé
            if result.get("result") is False:                
                currentDateTime = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                print(currentDateTime)
                query = "update emails set statut = 'PENDING', last_execution_date = str_to_date('"+currentDateTime+"', '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s'), last_execution_message = '"+result.get('message')+"' ,last_execution_result = 'NOK' where id = "+str(email.id)
                connection.execute(query)
            else:
                currentDateTime = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                print(currentDateTime)
                query = "update emails set statut = 'DONE', last_execution_date = str_to_date('"+currentDateTime+"', '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s'), last_execution_message = '"+result.get('message')+"' ,last_execution_result = 'OK' where id = "+str(email.id)
                connection.execute(query)

        session.close()
```

Il also found out that the problem is not only related with this application but all the python script i have on this server behave the same way.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Try `from .workers.Worker import Worker`

Comment: @Megalng when i try it i get this error message: no module named __main__.workers; '__main__' is not a package

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more of the traceback. Also, you may need to post the contents of **init**.py in the workers directory. I can get your code to run fine on my Windows machine.

There are two things that could be the source of your error:

1. Your import statement in **init**.py should look like

   ```
   import workers.Worker
   ```
2. It could be that the way your script (run.py) is launched, the default directory is C:\Windows. If you launch it from a shortcut, make sure in the properties that you set the "Start in:" directory correctly. You can get Python to tell you what directory it is working in with os.getcwd() (which is "get current working directory" from the os module). Try adding these lines to the very top of run.py (BEFORE "import workers.Worker import Worker") to help debug:
       import os
       print(os.getcwd())
   This will print the current working director in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the issue by removing and reinstalling python on the server.